# How to add link in Python docstring?

Tags: python, api, hyperlink, documentation, docstring

I have a function in python 3.x

```
def foo():
"""Lorem ipsum for more info, see here""
```

I want to add a hyperlink to 'here' to point to a website. How can I do that without installing external plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the link as a string into the docstring, like so:

```
def foo():
    """Lorem ipsum for more info, see here: www.myfancydocu.com""
```

The doctring is just a string, so there is no Hyperlink. But anyone that wants to look at the website can just copy the link.

There are automatic documentation-builders that build a documentation  out of your code and docstrings in e.g. html. Those can probably add hyperlinks to the documentation with a specific syntax, but that syntax then depends on which documentation-builder you use. If you only have your code, then just adding the url as a string is all you can do.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using sphinx to generate your documentation

```
""" 

`here <url>`__

"""
```

in your docstrings should be parsed properly.